# Owl Carousel dissapears after initial load without a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Owl Carousel and for the most part it is working exactly as I had hoped. However, after loading on my main page, if I navigate away from the page and then return (via a link) or even if I click my logo which will take me to the same main page, the carousel dissapears. It will only reappear if I actually refresh the browser, not if I navigate there by link. I am using Rails 4.1 and Bootstrap 3, though I do not believe those to be the problem. Perhaps they are though?

To understand what I'm saying you can visit http://enigmatic-brushlands-2071.herokuapp.com/

I have noticed in the .css for the owl carousel it sets the display to none until init

```
/* display none until init */
.owl-carousel{
display: none;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
-ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

If I change this display value the items I have show up but they do not appear correctly (they are very large). For some reason it is not changing the display value when I navigate back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is turbolinks.

try adding

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

to the Gemfile, and then make sure in you application.js you have first require on jquery, then require on jquery.turbolinks, then require all of your custom js, and then require turbolinks themselves. here is an example

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel
//= require_tree .

//= require turbolinks
```

home this helps